# Support rotation management software for small agile team of developers

Tags: project-management, scheduling

I'm looking for software for approximately 10 software developers working in Scrum fashion that can be used to schedule and manage L1 support for developers. We had a system where each developer did L1 support on one day of the week, if someone wasn't able to do so, they just found somebody else from the team to cover for them on that day and then they returned the favour on another time. However now with 10 people, this system is very problematic and we are looking for some simple software rota schedule management tool that could help with this. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of examples from the past are:

- [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/)
- [ABC Roster](http://www.abc-roster.com/)

Check out their websites.